# Change font size in legend

Tags: fontsize, tikz-styles, legend

I have the following tikz plot figure.
I want the legend to have a smaller text.
I would prefer to just scale it by 0.5.
Is there any easy way to do that?
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{,graphicx,placeins}
\usepackage{caption}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north}} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both, 
xlabel={Uhrzeit in [h]}, 
ylabel={Wartezeit in [s]}, 
ymin=0, 
ymax=55.435082191265906, 
xmin=6, 
xmax=19
]
\addplot[black] 
coordinates{
 (6,19.714285714285907) (7,17.414173228346648) (8,15.86666666666687) (9,15.117968750000136) (10,10.937606837606978) (11,15.951162790697827) (12,16.243478260869757) (13,20.82905405405423) (14,15.520279720279866) (15,16.44322580645179) (16,14.754666666666811) (17,14.783116883117078) (18,19.68227848101285) (19,14.841176470588383)
};
\addlegendentry{Durchschnitt} % here i want the smaller font size %
\addplot[red] 
coordinates{ 
(6,0.2359500250003066) (7,1.071518255698571) (8,0.6504365116407858) (9,0.7447067990664618) (10,0.22871614119400085) (11,0.534234896555887) (12,1.2147781092474457) (13,1.2819929607640965) (14,0.4373824916617135) (15,0.5552616389471527) (16,0.41528276544320875) (17,0.7275856348732841) (18,1.0135369783306665) (19,3.552713678800501E-15)
};
\addlegendentry{Untere SD Hülle} % here i want the smaller font size %
\addplot[blue] 
coordinates{ 
(6,41.17888800387077) (7,41.69703425197403) (8,37.833765218897895) (9,42.15804731911563) (10,35.76484552611063) (11,41.31045409644057) (12,40.77620227113837) (13,45.435082191265906) (14,41.91921488631313) (15,40.83993866894958) (16,40.4444824092698) (17,37.137716578028815) (18,42.989957303909605) (19,41.8468617029289)
};
\addlegendentry{Obere SD Hülle} % here i want the smaller font size %
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Wartezeit}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean like adjusting the font size in the legend style: `\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north,font=\footnotesize}}`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but seeing as it is your first question here, some general advice: Try to avoid `H` placement of figures, it almost never looks good (typically `ht` will work just fine), loading `pdfplots` should automatically load `graphicx` (just like `tikz` does) so you do not normally need it, `hyperref` should almost always be put last in the list of packages to avoid errors, `inputenc` is deprecated, i.e. it doesn't hurt to have it, but it is not required. If you load an option globally (like `ngerman`) you do not need to use it as an option in a package (`babel`).

Comment: @MarkusG. thanks, this is a very specific document though with almost only figures, thats why i dont want the floating.

Comment: thanks for the font tip. in overleaf that leads to "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/font'". Am I missing an import?

Comment: Have you by any change placed the `font` information outside of the append style?

Comment: yes i did and i just realized it. sorry and thanks!

Comment: one more thing that might be interesting regarding your hints: if i remove the ngerman package i will not get german figure names (Figure instead of Abbildung). If i remove it from the document class but not from the packages it will work though.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember there was something about that. Maybe I remembered incorrectly. The basic principal still applies to the other options though (i.e. a4paper being passed to `geometry`, although A4 is the default of KOMA class documents anyway)